# Symfony Localized Routes - Optional Locale

Tags: symfony, routes

I'd like the following urls to serve the appropriate actions:

- / - indexAction
- /fr - indexAction
- /foo - detailsAction (slug = foo)
- /fr/foo - detailsAction (slug = foo)

I have added the following action methods:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}", name="home", defaults={"_locale": ""}, requirements={"_locale": "fr|es"})
 */
public function indexAction() {
    ...
}

/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}/{slug}", name="details", defaults={"_locale": ""}, requirements={"_locale": "fr|es"})
 */
public function detailsAction($slug) {
    ...
}
```

This works fine if I go to /, /fr and /fr/foo. However when I go to /foo it doesn't find a matching route. I'd appreciate it if someone could show me how to this.

Please note that ideally i'd like to achieve this without having to add multiple @Route annotations for a particular action method. That way I can use the UrlGenerator and point to the same name to produce the localized and none localized route whether I pass the _locale parameter or not.

Comment: Have you tired using https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle? This seems to match exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks but I'm using my own framework and only using certain Symfony components. I'll look at how they've done things to try and get an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this to work although my solution is slightly hacky. First I removed {_locale} part of the path, the defaults and requirements from my routes above.

Then when I created my routes I said:

```
$routes = new RouteCollection();

// Load the routes
...

$routes->addPrefix('/{_locale}', ['_locale' => ''], ['_locale' => '|fr|es']);
```

This automatically adds the localization bits (removed above) to the routes so it can easily be configured in one place. I changed RouteCollection to my own type with the following:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection as BaseRouteCollection;

class RouteCollection extends BaseRouteCollection {
    public function addPrefix($prefix, array $defaults = [], array $requirements = []) {
        foreach ($this->all() as $route) {
            $route->setPath($prefix . rtrim($route->getPath(), '/'));
            $route->addDefaults($defaults);
            $route->addRequirements($requirements);
        }
    }
}
```

This makes sure the localized home page route doesn't end with a forward slash e.g. /fr/.

Finally I had to override the Route class with the following:

```
use ReflectionProperty;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route as BaseRoute;

class Route extends BaseRoute {
    public function compile() {
        // Call the parent method to get the compiled route
        $compiledRoute = parent::compile();

        // Override the regex property
        $property = new ReflectionProperty($compiledRoute, 'regex');
        $property->setAccessible(true);
        $property->setValue($compiledRoute, str_replace('^/', '^/?', $compiledRoute->getRegex()));

        return $compiledRoute;
    }
}
```

This is particularly hacky but does save you from having to add a heap more code. All it does is replace the regular expression so that the first forward slash is optional which allows the /foo url to work. Note: You will have to make sure your RouteCollection is a collection of this class and not the Symfony Route class.

Hope this helps.